# KeyBinding not working when switching Windows

Tags: c#, .net, binding, input, key-bindings

My MainWindow has some KeyBindings:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
   <KeyBinding Command="{Binding NewFileCommand}" Key="{Binding NewFileCommand.Key}" Modifiers="{Binding NewFileCommand.Modifiers}"  />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

They´re working, as long as i clicked somewhere into the content of my Window. But if I use Alt+Tab to switch between Applications (let´s say MS Word and my App) the Shortcuts won´t work  anymore until I click again somewhere into the View. Same when selecting the Application-Window via Mouse on the Border.

How can I make them working?

Comment: This works fine for me in my repro - what OS are you using?  What is your key and what are you modifiers?  Also, what type is the command that you are binding to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my repro, I used the [RelayCommand](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/26/using-relaycommands-in-silverlight-and-wpf.aspx) from [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) which worked fine.  I'm guessing that you are using something else.  Try adding this code in your window:

```
private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

That tells the command framework that something has changed and it should re-evaluate the CanExecute status of each command.

Comment: thanks. I registered on the Activated-Event and called Keyboard.Focus() to an IInputElement. Then the Bindings work as expected